# Excel VBA gives type mismatch on dividing decimal numbers after split

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code, which takes a string temp, which for sure has 2 numbers separated by a "(", and then does a couple of mathematical operations on them. I am getting a type mismatch error when trying to do the math, though, despite using CDec to convert them to a decimal number. What can I be doing wrong? Thanks.

```
    tempArry = Split(temp, " ")
    tolTemp = (CDec(tempArry(LBound(tempArry)) + tempArry(LBound(tempArry) + 2))) / 2
    noms(j) = tolTemp
    tols(j) = tolTemp - CDec(tempArry(LBound(tempArry)))
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with CDec, but what type of array is your tempArry? Is it a string array? If so, that might be causing an issue in the decimal conversion.  Try sending the values from tempArry to a new, float Array, then use that float array to do the math.

Comment: You mention that `temp` has 2 numbers separated by a `(` but in the code you split by space. A typo? Regardless, could you update your answer with 1 or 2 examples of values that are failing? Also the types of the variables being used.

Comment: Yes, sorry they are seperated by a space. I was confusing it with a later peice of code. An example of the temp variable that comes in is "112.34 min 117.89 max".

Comment: Also, BruceWayne, when I try to dim the tempArry beforehand it tell me that split can't assign to an array.

Comment: It seems you're missing a closing parens and a call do `CDec`. Should be `tolTemp = (CDec(tempArry(LBound(tempArry))) + CDec(tempArry(LBound(tempArry) + 2))) / 2`

Comment: Oh, I see my mistake now. Didn't think that to add them required decimals, as well. Thanks a ton! You should also add this as an answer so I can give you proper recognition and others can see it more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments it seems you're assuming you can add two strings as numbers.

Since the input (the `temp` variable) is a string, the array elements you're trying to add are also strings so when you write `tempArry(LBound(tempArry)) + tempArry(LBound(tempArry) + 2)` the output will be the concatenation of both strings (which is `112.34117.89` -- hence the *type mismatch*).

To solve it convert both to decimal *before* trying to add them:

```
tolTemp = (CDec(tempArry(LBound(tempArry))) + CDec(tempArry(LBound(tempArry) + 2))) / 2
```